# RunID is coming as manual even if the DAG is being scheduled using TriggerDagRunOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am triggering my DAG automatically using scheduled time and `TriggerDagRunOperator`, but the `run_id` is coming as manual_(time). I want that the `run_id` to come as scheduled or something but not manual to distinguish it with manually triggered DAG. I am using Airflow 2.

Issue: `TriggerDagOperator` also generates a `run_id` inside it's execute method, right? So, we are using that `run_id` for our pipeline. The problem is that `run_id` comes as `manual_` and then timestamp. I want this `manual` should get replace with triggered or something scheduled.

Comment: Sorry but I don't correctly understood your question, `TriggerDagRunOperator` allows to trigger a `DAG` inside another `DAG`

Comment: TriggerDagOperator also generates a "run_id" inside it's execute method, right? So, we are using that "run_id" for our pipeline, but the problem is that "run_id" comes as "manual_ and then timestamp". I want that this "manual" should get replace with *triggered* or something *scheduled*

Comment: I think you can override the operator and in the execute method replace `manual` by `triggered`. I can add an answer to show you an example if you are interested.

Comment: Hi @Agupta, did the above comment help?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, If anyone has some scripts ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun, Yes, please, if you can share the code in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I share with you a way to override the `TriggerDagRunOperator` operator.
In this case, we can interact with the current context, apply a logic based on the current `run_id` and override the `run_id` param with new calculated field in the operator, the code should look like :

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import datetime
from typing import List, Dict, Optional, Union

from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator


class CustomTriggerDagRunOperator(TriggerDagRunOperator):

    def __init__(self,
                 trigger_dag_id: str,
                 trigger_run_id: Optional[str] = None,
                 conf: Optional[Dict] = None,
                 execution_date: Optional[Union[str, datetime.datetime]] = None,
                 reset_dag_run: bool = False,
                 wait_for_completion: bool = False,
                 poke_interval: int = 60,
                 allowed_states: Optional[List] = None,
                 failed_states: Optional[List] = None,
                 **kwargs) -> None:
        super(CustomTriggerDagRunOperator, self).__init__(
            trigger_dag_id=trigger_dag_id,
            trigger_run_id=trigger_run_id,
            conf=conf,
            execution_date=execution_date,
            reset_dag_run=reset_dag_run,
            wait_for_completion=wait_for_completion,
            poke_interval=poke_interval,
            allowed_states=allowed_states,
            failed_states=failed_states,
            **kwargs
        )

   def execute(self, context):
      current_trigger_run_id = self.trigger_run_id

      # Apply your logic.
      self.trigger_run_id = ...

      super(CustomTriggerDagRunOperator, self).execute(context)
```

- Create a class `CustomTriggerDagRunOperator` that extends `TriggerDagRunOperator` operator.
- Override the constructor of the operator.
- Apply your logic based on the `trigger_run_id` field.
- Call the `execute` method on the parent operator.